# How do I create and use a script to repeat the -m function in SOX?

Tags: sox

I have a folder of audio files that I want to mix each with a named other file. So the output folder would have all the input folder files but with the named other file mixed in.

I can do this with -m but dont know how to create a script to do this for all the files.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: So, you have a folder with N audio files in it. You want to mix each of them with an other file (hence, you'll produce other N files), and then give to the output files a proper name. Is this what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you want.

(in bash) If you have `file1.wav`, `file2.wav` ... `filen.wav` and a `common.wav` try

```
for a in file*.wav
do
  sox -m "$a" common.wav "common-$a"
done
```

To obtain `common-fil2.wav`, `common-file2.wav`etc.

(untested)